# Ionic2 Card - to- slide Layout 9Gag Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ionic2

I've been trying to use Ionic2 to replicate the UI/Ux in 9gag mobile apps and also http://m.9gag.com where the initial post is a card scroll but upon click of a post/card the layout opens a slider page that user can swipe to show posts.

How can this be done in angular2

Here is the code for the cards layout.

```
<ion-card (click)='openSlide()'>
  <img src="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/boaty-mcboatface-sets-off-on-maiden-voyage-23.jpg"/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
     Maiden
      </ion-card-title>
    <p>
      Voyage
    </p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: i dont understand what the image is for

Comment: I swear I've seen the exact same question posted like 2 days ago.

Comment: Yeah, I did post it but it was wrongly worded.

Comment: I have updated it @DmitrySavy